# Pairwise cosine similarity

Tags: cosine-similarity

I'm a little confused when I read this paper:Pairwise Document Similarity in Large Collections with MapReduce
http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/publications/Elsayed_etal_ACL2008_short.pdf
In this paper, the author seems didn't consider word only appears in one document, but according to the definition of cosine similarity, we need to consider this situation, right?

The material I used is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nctb66hh84ab32c/postings-Reuters-data

The java code I used is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aklviixup4uulmu/CosineSimilarity.java

And the results I generated is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ea6ov7l7yut7yfj/part-00000

In the results, I see a lot of 1's and even number bigger than 1. I think it's kind of weird, could someone help me find out the reason? Thanks.